# Triggering a GTM event with Mailchimp pop up form submission

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, mailchimp

I have the standard Mailchimp pop up embedded on my site. I would like to trigger a GTM event every time it's submitted to send to GA.  It's an embedded iframe and I'm not seeing a way to handle this.  This is the embed code for the pop up:

```
<script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/xxxx/xxxx.js");</script>
```

I've tried reviewing the form class, form element and other form triggers, but nothing is triggering the GTM event.

Answer (score 1):

GTM's "Form Submission" trigger cannot catch form submissions in (embedded) iframes.

If you are only interested in the submit, you can add a custom event listener via a "Custom HTML" tag which pushes a custom event to dataLayer which you can then act on in GTM.

```
document.querySelector('#PopupSignupForm_0 div.mc-modal iframe').contentDocument.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event){dataLayer.push({event: 'mailchimp_submit'})});
```

This triggers every time the "subscribe" button is clicked - also when the form does not validate.

Maybe it is better to use a [Timer trigger](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679323?hl=en) which checks for a "MCPopupSubscribed" cookie with the value "yes"?

1. Create a Variable "MCPopupSubscribed", 1st Party Cookie, Cookie Name: "MCPopupSubscribed", Format Value: Convert undefined to "no"
2. Create a Variable "TimerID", Data Layer Variable, "gtm.timerId", Version 2
3. Create a Trigger "Mailchimp", Timer, Event Name: "gtm.timer", Interval: 1000, Enable ...: MCPopupSubscribed does not equal yes, Fires on some timers: MCPopupSubscribed equals yes
4. Create your tag, fires on "Mailchimp" trigger
5. Create a Tag "Clear Timer", Custom HTML, fires on "Mailchimp" trigger

   if ({{TimerID}}) {
       window.clearInterval({{TimerID}});
     }

The Timer will only "run" if the cookie is absent. It then checks every second if the cookie was set. If it is set it runs your tag and it runs "Clear Timer" to stop the timer/trigger. If it the timer is not stopped the trigger keeps firing every second.

There's also a cookie `MCPopupClosed=yes` which is set if the user closes the popup...

Comment: The time trigger is not a very elegant solution. It's heavy. Better to avoid, similarly to how you'd avoid the element visibility trigger. How do you know what to listen for on the mailchimp iframe? I tried googling their documentation on submit callbacks or submit window messages, but couldn't find anything. Also, won't you have the submission/validation details in the event details?

Comment: @bnazaruk Mailchimp does not provide any submit callbacks or messages. At least for their embedded form. That's why I suggest the heady timer trigger solution. Tracking _successful_ submissions seems to be not possible anyway. On submit user is navigated to a 3rd party website to solve captcha and won't return.

Comment: @TimW I added the custom event to GTM, but I'm not seeing anything change in the data layer upon submission in preview.  Can you tell me where I should look to see that?  I'm looking under the Data Layer tab on the GTM debugging screen.  Thanks!

Comment: @BNazaruk I like the data layer approach, but I'm not see anything change in the data layer when the solution from TimW was implemented.  Do you have any troubleshooting tips?

Comment: Subscribe button is in an iframe. You can't listen to clicks in an iframe. You can't even look into what's there. No, if mailchimp doesn't provide callbacks then it has to provide an ability to deploy your own callbacks with its iframe to then pop the messages to parent. Otherwise the thing is just untrackable.